# How to maintain Drools global counter for facts and apply rules based on its value

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I am new to Drools and working on a requirement where I will get batch of facts ( BankAccount information ) . I have to give alert message when three consecutive Minor Accounts ( age<16) inserted in session working memory. I have tried maintaining global variable and incrementing it when minor account inserted. But  I am not able to define a rule based on global counter value using which I have to deliver an alert message. Please find below DRL file and provide the solution for this.

The below rule is not firing

```
 rule checkCounterAndProduceAlert when
       b: ResultFact( value > 2 )   
    then
        System.out.println("Alert****");  
    end

Here is the DRL full content of DRL file




        package com.ys.drools.rules

import com.ys.drools.facts.*;

rule checkCounterAndProduceAlert 

no-loop true
when
   b: ResultFact( value > 2 )   
then
    System.out.println("Alert****");  
end


rule checkSeriesOfMinorAccount when
    a : AccountHolder( age < 16 )
    b : ResultFact()
then
b.inc();
update(b);

System.out.println("Incrementing count  since minor account appered");
System.out.println("***********************************************");
System.out.println(b.getValue());
end


rule checMajorAccount when
    a : AccountHolder( age >16 )
    b :ResultFact()
then
b.reset();
update(b);
System.out.println("Making count zero since major account appered");
System.out.println(b.getValue());
end
```

Here is the Java class Which will load 3 Minor accounts and Test the application

```
package com.ys.drools.data.loader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.ys.drools.facts.AccountHolder;
import com.ys.drools.util.BankAccountUtilService;
import com.ys.drools.util.DroolsGlobalUtil;

public class Test {
    private BankAccountUtilService service;
    private  KieContainer kieContainer;
    private KieSession kieSession;
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(Test.class);

    private List<AccountHolder> accountHolders=new ArrayList<AccountHolder>();  

    public Test(){
        kieContainer= KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();     
          kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("BankAccountSession");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Test test=new Test();
        List<AccountHolder> aList=test.fillAccountHolderList();
         ResultFact fact=new ResultFact();
       test.kieSession.insert(fact);
       for(int i=0;i<aList.size();i++){
        test.kieSession.insert(aList.get(i));
        test.kieSession.fireAllRules();
        }

      }


    public List<AccountHolder> fillAccountHolderList(){
         List<AccountHolder> accountHolders=new ArrayList<AccountHolder>(); 
         AccountHolder a1=new AccountHolder("Karun", 12);
         AccountHolder a2=new AccountHolder("kumar", 12);
         AccountHolder a3=new AccountHolder("rakesh", 10);
         accountHolders.add(a1);
         accountHolders.add(a2);
         accountHolders.add(a3);
         return accountHolders; 
    }
}
```

Please provide the solution for this. Output when Running test class

```
Incrementing count  since minor account appered
***********************************************
1
Incrementing count  since minor account appered
***********************************************
2
Incrementing count  since minor account appered
***********************************************
3
Making count zero since major account appered
0
```

("Alert****") is not displaying even after value is >2 . rule "checkCounterAndProduceAlert" is not firing

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.

```
class Counter {
    private int value;
    public void inc(){ value++; }
    public void reset(){ value = 0; }
    public int getValue(){ return value; }
}
```

Insert a Counter fact into working memory and use methods `inc` and `reset` where appropriate after adding a `$c: Counter()` pattern to the rules.

```
rule checkCounterAndProduceAlert when
    Counter( value == 3 )   
then
    System.out.println("Alert****");  
end
```

You may need a specification whether another alert should be issued after the sixth, ninth,... account of a minor in a row.

**Edit**

You can also declare and insert this in the DRL file:

```
declare Counter
  value : int
end

rule "insert counter"
  salience 999999
when
  not Counter()
then
  insert( new Counter() );
end
```

Comment: thanks for the response . Could you please explain where I need to declare this Counter fact in DRL file ?  Because actual rules I am applying on different fact and in  then part I should increment or reset counter . Do i need to declare this a global again..?

Comment: Note that I wrote "insert a Counter fact". See my update. - No globals.

Comment: Thanks for update. I have edited the DRL content please go through that and help me in fixing issue. I am inserting ResultFact to working memory through a java program . Other methods inc and reset are working fine and I am able to print counter value using getValue method But "rule checkCounterAndProduceAlert " is not firing

Comment: I don't see an `insert( new ResultFact() );` in your code.

Comment: Please check now               ResultFact fact=new ResultFact();
       test.kieSession.insert(fact);     Please help me in resolving this.. I am also adding the console output. everything is fine except that rule is not firing when value>2

Comment: Oh, you'll have to wrap the inc and reset calls on Counter facts in modify statements, or call update on the fact. Sorry, I thought you'd know this... Very basic...

Comment: I have updated the Result fact and its working. But how to avoid infinite loop ? after adding update fact line in drl file It is executing continuously

Comment: What, exactly, do you have in your DRL file now?

Comment: I have updated DRL file in question.Please look at it and help me with solution

Comment: You need no-loop on the rules with update calls, not on the one displaying the alert.

Comment: No luck..same result